# XAMPP/SQLSRV: Unable to find Sqlsrv in PHPINFO(); - errors coming from connection

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, xampp, sqlsrv

I'm attempting to connect into a SQL Server DB I have hosted on my Linux VM. I'm running xampp on my development windows machine and the connection is coming from a php site I'm building. I figured I'd need to use `sqlsrv` to connect in. I downloaded the dll's from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2019

I've moved the necessary dll files to my `xampp\php\etc\` directory. I've also verified the extension directory in the php.ini file is `extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"`

The following have been added to the `Dynamic Extensions` section of the php.ini:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_81_ts_x86.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_81_ts_x86.dll
extension=php8ts.dll
```

I've found info online about removing the `php_` prefix, removing the `.dll` suffix, using ts or non ts, moving all files into the extensions directory, moving only the couple listed above into the directory, not including `php8ts.dll`, etc. I've tried every configuration of the above, both logical and illogical.

Here's a sample connection code for my site:

```php
$conn = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server=my_server_ip\\MSSQLSERVER;Database=dbname', 'username', 'password');
if ($conn === false) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_connect): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
} else {
    echo "success";
}
```

I've tried multiple different connection examples. With the one above, I receive this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\index.php:123 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\site\index.php(123): PDO->__construct('sqlsrv:Server=my_server_ip', 'username', 'password') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\index.php on line 123

From here I logically thought okay, let's check `phpinfo();` by echoing it. There is nothing at all listed for `sqlsrv` or the PDO variant anywhere on the list. Even ctrl+f on the page for sqlsrv, the only thing that is found is the error above.

I have verified I have the ODBC drivers installed.

[image]

The other things I've tried was to use `sqlsrv_connect` instead of PDO. I found conflicting information on this working for my php version (8.1), but figured let's try it anyway. However when I run into that variant, I get:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()

It seems obvious to me my .dlls are not being recognized or something of the sort. However I cannot for the life of me understand why. I've verified everything is ran as admin, restarted xampp multiple times, removed/redownloaded the dlls, etc.

Can anyone point out any glaring problems I may not be thinking of?

Comment: Don't forget to load the `php_pdo.dll` extension.

Comment: You're looking at ODBC Data Source Administrator (64-bit)... but configuring PHP to use the 32-bit x86 drivers? That seems like an issue.

Comment: @Zhorov can you explain why that's needed, and where I could find it? In my extension directory of xampp I do not have a `php_pdo` dll, I do however have dlls `php_pdo_` followed by sqlite, pgsql, odbc, oci, mysql, and firebird. From looking at the PHP site, everything seems to point towards just using `pdo_sqlsrv`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Weirdly enough, I have 32-bit and 64-bit ODBC Data Sources in the Windows Administrative Tools which happened from the only installation I've done. I tried with both x86 and x64 to no avail, the same problem.

Comment: That's not weird. 32-bit and 64-bit data sources are configured separately and independent from one another. But if you're on a 64-bit Windows then likely you have a 64-bit PHP and it needs to use the 64-bit drivers.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thanks for that! I re-tried just now after my comment verifying the 64 bit DLLs are present, and the issue is still prevalent. I'm wondering if this is some sort of Xampp installation issue - it just can't seem to find the DLLs at all judging from `phpinfo();`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - solved the issue, added an edit to the post. Very weird behavior out of Xampp. Even with the x64 dll's in the ini, Xampp was attempting to utilize the x86 dlls. It's almost as if the ini was searching for a prefix (something like php_pdo_sqlsrv) instead of the entire dll name written out, and then choosing the x86 variant. Wondering if there's some sort of precedent to how a dll is chosen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. There were two problems.

1. My Xampp installation was corrupt. It wouldn't recognize ANY new DLLs I noticed from using `echo phpinfo();` on my page.
2. The ini file configuration was attempting to use the x86 dll's instead of the x64's for some reason, even when the extensions were written in the ini as x64.

Steps to solve:

1. I reinstalled and reconfigured Xampp with default settings once more, and dll's were now recognized.
2. I removed the x86 dll's from the extensions directory of Xampp.

The final php.ini is as such:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_81_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_81_ts_x64.dll
extension=php8ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
extension=php_pdo.dll
```

Utilizing the final .dll may be redundant, but it still works as intended. Make sure you verify the correct version of sqlsrv or pdo_sqlsrv, as compatibility issues with your phpversion may occur.